# Error on debug if naming a textarea with _txt ending in flash cs 4 AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, adobe, flash-cs4

I was doing a tutorial, and i notice that if i put the name of a text area with a _txt ending i end up with this error

> TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert fl.controls::TextArea@1ef0221 to fl.controls.TextInput.

anybody knows why ?

Comment: Post the relevant code - error is somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that it's a naming issue? It sounds like you may have used the wrong component or are casting it incorrectly in your code. If you could post your code, that would be helpful.